# Reading cobol file line by line seperated by new line character

Tags: cobol

I'm having trouble reading a file line-by-line. This is a current snippet of the code:

```
file-control.
    select input-file
    assign input-file-name
    organization is sequential
file section.
    fd input-file.
    01 input-file-record picturex(25)
working-storage section.
01 ws-eof picture a(1).
```

and here's where I actually read in the file:

```
perform until ws-eof = 'Y'
    read input-file into input-file-record
    at end move 'Y' to ws-eof
    not at end
        display input-file-record
    end-read
end-perform
    close input-file
```

The problem is, i'm trying to read the file line by line, but it seems like it's just filling up 25 characters, then reading again instead of looping by the return character in the text file.

The text file would look something like this:

```
AAAA
BBBB
CCCC
DDDD
```

Comment: what does your actual output look like? Are you running on a mainframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The problem is, i'm trying to read the file line by line, but it seems like it's just filling up 25 characters, then reading again instead of looping by the return character in the text file.

The system is exactly doing what you tell it to do:

```
organization is sequential             *>  sequential, fixed length
01 input-file-record picture x(25)     *>  the fixed length is 25 bytes
```

Depending on the compiler you use (it is always a good idea to specify this if there isn't a specific tag for it already that you can use, and even in this case the version number never harms) you can either use the common extension (which *may* even get standard with COBOL 202x):

```
organization is line sequential        *>  sequential, read until line break found
```

or have to read it sequential (in this case likely with a bigger size) and

inspect file-rec converting all x'0d' by x'0a' *> if you expect windows or mac line breaks
   move 1 to strpoint
   unstring file-rec
      delimited by all x'0a'
      into real-rec
      with pointer strpoint
   end-unstring

Comment: The `organization is sequential` to `organization is line sequential` did the trick. Thanks!